# How to install Node.js and NPM in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, node.js

I am trying to install the wallet for IOTA, as described [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet). 
I run but the command is not found. I am not clear which package `npm` is in `apt search npm` where I do not find the corresponding application.

```
npm install -g electron
```

The application is in the package NodeJS [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and corresponding download is `Linux Binaries (x86/x64)` in the platfrom. Studying the download

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64/bin$ ./npm 
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
masi@masi:~/Downloads/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64/bin$ ls -la
total 34384
drwxrwxr-x 2 masi masi     4096 Nov  7 22:56 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 masi masi     4096 Nov  7 22:56 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 masi masi 35198210 Nov  7 22:56 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 masi masi       38 Dec  5 18:22 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 masi masi       38 Dec  5 18:22 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

### Almost working attempt, testing GAD3R

1. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```

   You get notification *## Run `apt-get install nodejs` (as root) to install Node.js v8.x and npm`*. But running it does no changes.

   A `nodesource.list` will be created under your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` by the above commmands

   ```
    deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch main
    deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch main
   ```
2. Run

   ```
    sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
   ```

   Output

   ```
    + electron@1.7.9
    added 152 packages in 125.983s
   ```
3. Change owners

   ```
    masi@masi:~/Downloads/wallet$ sudo chown -R masi:masi 
    /usr/lib/node_modules/
   ```
4. Run

   ```
    sudo npm install -g bower
   ```

   Output

   ```
   npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
   /usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
   + bower@1.8.2
   updated 1 package in 1.714s
   ```
5. Test ([here](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet) below *Instructions* heading)

   ```
   masi@masi:~/Downloads/wallet$ sudo npm start

   npm ERR! path /home/masi/package.json
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! errno -2
   npm ERR! syscall open
   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/masi/package.json'
   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
   npm ERR! enoent 

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /home/masi/.npm/_logs/2017-12-07T18_52_27_750Z-debug.log
   ```

OS: Debian Stretch 9.1

Answer (score 5):

To install Node.js and `npm` use the `setup` script (e.g: Nod.js V8):

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

A `nodesource.list` will be created under your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the following content :

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch main
```

Then install `electron` and `brower`:

```
npm install -g electron
npm install -g bower
```

Official website : [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

**Update**

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'

[Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

> You may receive an EACCES error when you try to install a package globally. This indicates that you do not have permission to write to the directories that npm uses to store global packages and commands.
>
> You can fix this problem using one of three options:
>
> 1. Change the permission to npm's default directory.
> 2. Change npm's default directory to another directory.
> 3. Install Node with a package manager that takes care of this for you.
>
> You should back-up your computer before moving forward.

A working solution on github : the [ander7agar's comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268) tested on debian Stretch:

```
sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

the same error will happen when installing `brower` , change the ownership of `node_modules`:

```
sudo chown -R masi:masi /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 If the command exit without error , electron should be installed correctly . Type `electron` on the terminal to start the application.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Install Node V8 then follow the instruction https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet#instructions , it will work for you ( maybe the problem come from the Node version it should be V8)

Comment: The setup script will automatically create a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` , i have installed `electron` , `brower` and  start the IOTA wallet using `npm start` without problem (Node V8)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 run `npm init` then `npm start`

Comment: I get https://paste.ubuntu.com/26134403/

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 the command `npm install` should install the dependencies , please run it under `wallet` after cloning `iri`

Comment: Please, see here https://paste.ubuntu.com/26134464/ What do you think?

Comment: Check `ls -l ~/.npm`  if it is owned by root change the ownership to masi `sudo chown -R masi:masi ~/npm`

Comment: All owned by masi, see https://paste.ubuntu.com/26134644/ What next possible troubleshoot strategy?

Comment: use `~/wallet` instead of `~/Downloads/wallet` (a clean install) If you see the `All ccurl dependencies have been downloaded.` ignore the others warning . on the [instruction](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet#instructions)  step the commands should be executed without `sudo` , in addition  run `npm init` before `npm start`